# editing swf bytecode at runtime?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to make a modification for World of tanks.
It use Scaleform and Action script 3.
Since edit Swf file each time is very long, i would like find a way to load code at runtime and then edit original scripts that are inside swf files.
How i can do this?

Comment: This looks like patching an executable. It might be possible if you'd get `loaderinfo.bytes` and load another SWF from patched `ByteArray`. But, recompiling that SWF is not possible from within AS3 code.

Comment: could be possible use something like this ? https://code.google.com/p/as3scriptinglib/

Comment: Maybe, you can try this approach. Given the lib's description, you can have an AS3 file, search/replace a certain string, compile it and run. But, if you want to target a standalone SWF, you need to decompile it first. Also decompiling then recompiling an SWF usually doesn't work without extra hassle, so maybe this is still impossible.

Comment: what sort of modifications are you trying to make? (aside from looking like you're trying to hack the game)

Comment: it's not a hack, in World of tanks exist thousand of mods and they are made decompiling swf to extract flex project, then rebuit and changed some ABC code. But since this is a long way, i would like edit swf on the fly with a lib or, since swf are first loaded from res_mods folder if it exist, create a new one with almost same content

Answer (score 1):

In your comments there are some approaches to edit on byte level. This requires advanced hacking and debugging tactics. Lots of this has to do with basic research which is based on adapt the source code in tiny steps, compile, compare the resulting code.

However when I read "...then edit original scripts..." in your question I wonder if you got the whole point:
You edit your code in text format. You compile your text code into binary data which does not at all contain any of your original textual source code. Well more precisely, nothing eventually except data values (if this is not compressed). Decompilation could potentially transform the binary back into actionscript or other languages - BUT for the price of having sense less function and variable names and also sometimes also less meaningful algorithms (due to code optimization at compile time).